# Failed to write to /dev/nvme-fabrics: Connection refused

Tags: networking, nvme, tcp-ip

I am trying to connect 2 Pc one as host and the other as the client to each other through nvme over tcp  so i have follwed this website of redhat https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/9/html/managing_storage_devices/configuring-nvme-over-fabrics-using-nvme-tcp_managing-storage-devices

but after doing all the steps I am getting this error
aarohnvme@nvme:~$ sudo nvme discover --transport=tcp --traddr=192.168.1.32 --host-traddr=192.168.1.170 --trsvcid=8009
**Failed to write to /dev/nvme-fabrics: Connection refused**
can anyone please help?

the os version of both the pc is
Os of aarohvme@192.168.1.170 is Distributor ID: Ubuntu Description: Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS Release: 22.04 Codename: jammy The Os of odroid@192.168.1.32 is Distributor ID: Ubuntu Description: Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS Release: 20.04 Codename: focal

Comment: Can you update your question with the operating system of the two PCs (including version)?

Comment: Os of aarohvme@192.168.1.170 is
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description: Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS
Release: 22.04
Codename: jammy

The Os of odroid@192.168.1.32 is 
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description: Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS
Release: 20.04
Codename: focal